# Zeroes of a non-zero entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, weierstrass-factorization

Let $f$ be a nonzero entire function such that $|f(z)|\leq e^{|z|}$. Can $f(\sqrt{n})=0$ for infinitely many $n$? We know that the Weierstrass Factor Theorem asserts that given any closed discrete set $A$ in $\mathbb{C}$, we can always find an entire function can assumes zero of any desired multiplicity at each point of $A$. I am trying to use the WFT but am reaching nowhere. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What of $f(z)=\sin(z\pi/200)$? Then $f(\sqrt{200^2n^2})=0$ for each integer $n$...

Comment: a function satisfying $|f(z)|\leq e^{|z|}$ is of order at most $1$ so it cannot have more than $O(R)$ zeroes in a disc of radius $R$; this means that while $f(\sqrt n)$ can obviously be zero infinitely many times as @Mindlack pointed out, there is a bound on the numbers of $n$ for which that happens and the example given is optimal; in particular we cannot have $f(\sqrt n)=0, n \ge n_0$

Comment: As Conrad said, it all comes down to the asymptotic number of zeros.  As long as there aren't too many, WFT will give you a function with the required growth rate.  Conversely from the growth rate of the function [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) allows you to bound the number of zeros, a result beautifully generalized in [Nevanlinna Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna_theory)